# Access actionbar from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to disable a button in my ActionBar from a class that extends AsyncTask. Im currently passing the actionbar menu to my task using the constructor, but im getting a null reference exception:

**Main Activity:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    actionbarMenu = menu;

    return true;
}
```

---

**AsyncTask class:**

```
protected void onPreExecute(){

    actionbarMenu.findItem(R.id.refresh).setEnabled(false);

}
```

How should I know when the menu is set from withing the AsyncTask?

Comment: As far as you call it onPreExecute() the easiest way is to check if menu item is null or not and if not, call setEnabled() on it.

Comment: @VladimirLichonos The problem is that it seems to always be null

Answer (score 0):

What you're not showing is the definition of the AsyncTask subclass or the constructor, or where you create the AsyncTask. onCreateOptionsMenu is only called if the options menu is invoked, when the options menu is displayed. If it hasn't been, then actionbarMenu will be null.